# How do I access a variable in one python script from another script

Tags: python, import

bot2.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/bot', methods=['POST'])
def bot():
    incoming_msg = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    constparam = incoming_msg

    print(constparam)
    msg.body(constparam)

    return str(resp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

dummy.py

```
from bot2 import app,bot
import time

while 1:

    print(bot.constparam)
    time.sleep(5)
```

I want to use constparam variable of bot2.py in dummy.py

Comment: What do you expect `print(bot.constparam)` to output before `bot()` has been called by the `Flask` framework?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with how Flask exposes its instances, but normally, any top-level variable or object can be imported and accessed. However, since `bot` is a function, all of its variables (including `constparam`) are private and only accessible within that function. One thing that you can do is to make `constparam` a global variable instead, where it can be accessed from any module that imports the file. Since you would start by setting the variable, you first will have to add a `global constparam` to the `bot` function before anything else to do with `constparam` occurs.

Comment: i just created a constparam as global but still i cant acess it.

Comment: By default, assigning to variables in a function will still create a local version. Make sure you added the `global constparam` line to declare that you want to use the *global* variable, and not create a local one. I forgot to directly mention it, but you will also have to add `constparam` to your import list and access it as a global variable instead of a property.